# Argument exception: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter of non-nullable type

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I got an error report from a user which tells me that on this method there happened an error:

```
public string SaveItem(int item_id,
                       string item_name,
                       int item_temp,
                       string item_number)
    {...}
```

The error is for the 'item_temp' parameter.

So this parameter was called as null. But here is how I fill this parameter in jquery, in the ajax call:

```
item_temp: ($('#myTextBox').val().length > 0 ? parseInt($('#myTextBox').val()) : -99999999),
```

How can it be called as null?

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce the behaviour the user saw? What happens if you enter a non-numeric value in the field in question, say "abc"? Or " " (a space character)? (And as an aside, _never_ use `parseInt()` on user-entered data without specifying the radix in the second parameter - if the user happens to enter a leading zero some browsers will interpret that as octal, while a leading "0x" causes the number to be taken as hexadecimal.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Then the method isn't even called. The error in the title doesn't happen.